# How to create a sequential count of IDs in SQL?

Tags: sql, sequential

I am working with a data frame that looks as follows:

| JOB_ID | APPLICANT_ID | DATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/01/2020 | Stage 1 |
| 1 | A | 01/01/2020 | Accepted |
| 2 | A | 01/01/2020 | Rejected |
| 1 | B | 02/01/2020 | Stage 1 |
| 1 | B | 02/02/2020 | Stage 2 |
| 1 | B | 02/03/2020 | Accepted |

And I want to add a field that counts sequentially the number of rows with the same Job ID and Applicant ID so that the result looks as follows:

| JOB_ID | APPLICANT_ID | DATE | STATUS | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/01/2020 | Stage 1 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 01/02/2020 | Accepted | 2 |
| 2 | A | 01/01/2020 | Rejected | 1 |
| 1 | B | 02/01/2020 | Stage 1 | 1 |
| 1 | B | 02/02/2020 | Stage 2 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 02/03/2020 | Accepted | 3 |

I've tried using:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(JOB_ID, APPLICANT_ID))
```

but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer may vary slightly based on the SQL dialect you are using, this would be the way to go about getting the desired result:

```sql
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JOB_ID, APPLICANT_ID ORDER BY DATE) AS COUNT
FROM
    INPUT_TABLE
```

Here `INPUT_TABLE` is the table you have provided as the input.